# How does one setup a color coin or issue a digital asset token using Ethereum?

Tags: tokens

Lets say I want to issue my own company shares using Ethereum. Currently Counterparty, Coloredcoins, and NXT can do this with their asset exchange.

- But how can this be done in Ethereum?
- And is there a a place I can browse these digital assets that others have setup? - Is there a tutorial on how to get my own digital token setup?